# Can I help the Galaxy S III browser recognize a street address?

Tags: android, web, galaxy, street-address

I'm always surprised and delighted when the web browser on my Android phone recognizes a phone number or a street address, and offers to call the number or map the address.

On a new web site I'm building, the address of the business is recognized on my Droid 4, but not on my wife's Samsung GS3.

Is there any way I can apply some mark up to the business address to help the browser recognize it?

Comment: Have an example? I'm on a GS3 now.

Comment: I do! http://lighthousepilates.com There's an address in the banner of the page. On my Droid 4 I can tap it to get a map link, but on my wife's GS3 it's not recognized.

Comment: Yes, it recognizes the phone number but not the address.

Comment: And how funny... I am .6 miles from there right now! Check out http://pgchristmas.com which also is not recognized (but fun to visit)

Comment: Small world. :) That's my sister's Pilates studio.